# Model is not passed to controller's action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnConfirmAddition').click(function () {
            var contractorId = $("#contractorId").val();
            var contactPerson = $("#addNewContactPersonForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddContactPerson", "Contractors")',
                type: "GET",
                data: { newContactPerson: contactPerson, contractorId: contractorId },
                //data: contactPerson,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    toastr.success("Success");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $("#errorArea").html(showError(data.ErrorMessage));
                    toastr.error(data.errorMessage);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

    public JsonResult AddContactPerson(ContactPerson newContactPerson, string contractorId)
    {
     //Some code
    }
```

When I pass parameters in ajax call as above, my newContactPerson is null and contractorId contains appropriate data. 
However when remove contractorId parameter from controller's action and pass parameter in ajax call as follows:

```
data: contactPerson
```

it works. I was wondering why? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Seems like this should be a `PUT` or `POST` - a `GET` for `AddContactPerson` seems wrong.

Comment: Try `var contactPerson = $("#addNewContactPersonForm").serializeArray();`

Comment: my contactPerson variable is fine, it contains correct data. I've also changed it to serializeArray but now, object is not null but all its fields are empty (in fact they are not empty but populated by me)

Comment: It may contain the correct data, but its not in the correct format.

Comment: these are just strings. In firebug I can see that contactPerson variable contains correct data but in my action, all fields are empty

Comment: @tymeJV obviously you are right, I've changed it to PUT but it does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post your data following way,

```
data: $("#addNewContactPersonForm").serialize() + '&contractorId='+ contractorId
```

And add data type to Ajax call,

```
 dataType: "json"
```

Comment: Yes! That works! Can you please explain me the difference between my solution and your solution?

Comment: If you wantd to post data your way then you have to make client side object of `ContactPerson ` and then assign it to newContactPerson. because serialization was doing `first name=Foo&last name=Bar` to your form. So MVC model binder has problem extracting data.

Comment: I thought asp.net takes care of that serialization